# Sql clause with left join causing column not found

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I´m trying to make a select in a bunch of tables (MySQL database) with a **left join** and it´s causing me a column not found:

**SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'per_idn_validacao' in 'on clause'**

Here is my sql statement:

```
SELECT pes_idn_pergunta_especificidade, 
pes_idn_tipo_especificidade, 
pes_idn_pergunta, 
pes_des_ordem, 
pes_flg_obrigatoriedade , 
tes_idn_tipo_especificidade, 
tes_des_descricao, 
pro_idn_programa, 
pro_des_descricao, 
per_idn_pergunta, 
per_idn_resposta, 
per_idn_validacao, 
per_idn_tipo, 
per_des_descricao, 
per_flg_autocompletar, 
per_des_ordem, 
per_des_strategy, 
per_des_hint, 
tpp_idn_tipo, 
tpp_des_descricao, 
tre_idn_tipo, 
tre_des_descricao 
FROM 
slt_pergunta_especificidade, 
slt_tipo_especificidade, 
slt_programa, slt_pergunta, 
slt_tipo_resposta, slt_tipo_pergunta 
LEFT JOIN slt_tipo_validacao ON per_idn_validacao = tvl_idn_validacao 
WHERE pro_idn_programa = tes_idn_programa 
AND tpp_idn_tipo = per_idn_tipo 
AND per_idn_pergunta = pes_idn_pergunta AND tre_idn_tipo = per_idn_resposta AND tes_idn_tipo_especificidade = pes_idn_tipo_especificidade 
AND pes_idn_tipo_especificidade = :id 
ORDER BY pes_des_ordem
```

Can anyone help me through this?

Comment: Do not mix explicit and implicit joins.  Simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.  That will fix your problem.

Comment: Scope, don't mix old style (implicit) join, with new style, explicit joins. Here "slt_tipo_pergunta LEFT JOIN slt_tipo_validacao" is executed before anything else, and only these two tables' columns are available in the ON clause.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jarlh. Could you please explain to me what is the best way in this case, what am i supposed to do? Thanks again.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your comment. Could you explain to me what i should do in this case?

Comment: I figured out your point @GordonLinoff. Please post an answer so i can give you the credit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query re-written using `JOIN` syntax only:
(NOTE: The columns in the `ON` predicates will need to be arranged such that no column appears before the table it resides in.

```
SELECT pes_idn_pergunta_especificidade, 
       pes_idn_tipo_especificidade, 
       pes_idn_pergunta, 
       pes_des_ordem, 
       pes_flg_obrigatoriedade , 
       tes_idn_tipo_especificidade, 
       tes_des_descricao, 
       pro_idn_programa, 
       pro_des_descricao, 
       per_idn_pergunta, 
       per_idn_resposta, 
       per_idn_validacao, 
       per_idn_tipo, 
       per_des_descricao, 
       per_flg_autocompletar, 
       per_des_ordem, 
       per_des_strategy, 
       per_des_hint, 
       tpp_idn_tipo, 
       tpp_des_descricao, 
       tre_idn_tipo, 
       tre_des_descricao 
FROM   slt_pergunta_especificidade
JOIN   slt_tipo_especificidade
   ON  pro_idn_programa = tes_idn_programa
JOIN   slt_programa
   ON  tpp_idn_tipo = per_idn_tipo
JOIN   slt_pergunta
   ON  per_idn_pergunta = pes_idn_pergunta
JOIN   slt_tipo_resposta
   ON  tre_idn_tipo = per_idn_resposta 
JOIN   slt_tipo_pergunta
   ON  tes_idn_tipo_especificidade = pes_idn_tipo_especificidade
LEFT JOIN slt_tipo_validacao
   ON  per_idn_validacao = tvl_idn_validacao 
WHERE  pes_idn_tipo_especificidade = :id 
ORDER BY pes_des_ordem
```